# Centre Emacs buffer within window

Tags: emacs

I wrap all my code at 80 columns, and there are times where the Emacs window is wider than 80 columns and there is a lot of unused whitespace on the right side.

I would like to position the Emacs buffer, so all the text is displayed in the middle of the window.

This is different to centre aligning text (more akin to the whitespace on either side of the text when viewing pdfs).

I think this can be achieved by dynamically adjusting the fringe mode widths, depending on the current window size, but I'm not sure where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: [writeroom-mode.el](https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode/blob/master/writeroom-mode.el) manages to do that; maybe reading the source provides some clues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As demonstrated [here](http://bzg.fr/emacs-strip-tease.html#sec-6) this is indeed possible:

```lisp
(set-fringe-mode
 (/ (- (frame-pixel-width)
       (* 80 (frame-char-width)))
    2))
```

However, as I am testing this I seem to have more luck with using margins, at least when also resizing my frame:

```lisp
(defun my-resize-margins ()
  (let ((margin-size (/ (- (frame-width) 80) 2)))
    (set-window-margins nil margin-size margin-size)))

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook #'my-resize-margins)
(my-resize-margins)
```

Comment: An answer on S.O. should provide at least a summary of the info you are linking to - a summary of what the solution is (how).

Comment: I have done as you suggested, is that better? Or should I have deleted my answer?

Comment: Great, this worked fine. Thanks. (Also there is an extra paren at the end of the second line on the second block of code)

Comment: `window-width` instead of `frame-width` works better when there are more than one window in the frame.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function which should do what you want, using margins instead of fringes (since I tend to display buffer boundaries in the fringe and I find it becomes ugly if the fringe is too large).

```lisp
(defun my/center (width)
  (interactive "nBuffer width: ")
  (let* ((adj          (- (window-text-width)
                          width))
         (total-margin (+ adj
                          left-margin-width
                          right-margin-width)))
    (setq left-margin-width  (/ total-margin 2))
    (setq right-margin-width (- total-margin left-margin-width)))
  (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern answer is https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti or https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode, both worked immediately for me where other things did not

Answer (score 1):

You ask to display the buffer in the center of the window, which just moves some of the extra whitespace to the left of the buffer, from the right.

How about a solution that eliminates that extra whitespace instead?  If that is acceptable, here are two approaches.

1. If the buffer is alone in its frame, then you can fit the frame to the buffer, using library [`fit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/fit-frame.el).  I bind command `fit-frame` to `C-x C-_`.  This saves space not only within Emacs but for your desktop.  (Library [`zoom-frm.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/zoom-frm.el) lets you also shrink/enlarge a frame incrementally, so you can save space by shrinking a frame when you don't need to see its content in detail.)
2. If not (so the buffer is shown in a frame where there are multiple windows), and if the buffer's window has another window to the left or right of it, then you can do one of the following:

   2a. If the buffer's window has another window to the left or right of it, then you can use command `fit-window-to-buffer`.  But you will also need to set option `fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally` to non-`nil`.

   2b. Use `C-{` (`shrink-window-horizontally`), followed by `C-x z z z...`, to incrementally shrink the window width (removing the extra whitespace).

   2c. Load library [`face-remap+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/face-remap%2b.el). Whenever you use text-scaling (e.g. `C-x C-` or `C-x =`), the window size grows or shrinks along with the text size, so you don't get extra whitespace added at the right when you shrink the text.  This is controlled by user option `text-scale-resize-window`.

Answer (score 1):

Center window mode

https://github.com/anler/centered-window-mode

Global minor mode that centers the text of the window.

If another window is visible the text goes back to normal if its width is less than "cwm-centered-window-width."