# Possible to make bzg-big-fringe mode in emacs work with linum or other line numbers?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to make [bzg-big-fringe mode](http://bzg.fr/emacs-strip-tease.html) in emacs work with [linum](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc7)?

This seems to require a modicum of hacking skills; just playing around with the settings in linum yields strange results. And if you just use linum without any adjustments the line numbers turn up so far away from the text that I can't use them with great precision.

Ps. alternative distraction free modes that work with linum will be accepted as answers. Also making some other line number mode work with bzg-big-fringe mode will be accepted.

Comment: There was a thread within the last couple of weeks that described how to use margins instead of fringes to achieve a centered text effect.  If you use margins, then it is just a matter of setting the distance between the line numbers and your text (e.g., right alignment of line numbers), and you could use a thin fringe of about 10 (or whatever suits your needs) to put just a little more distance between the line numbers and your text.

Comment: Was it this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313198/changing-margin-for-emacs-text-mode ? Will have to look at later and try implementing. Sound like a good tip except for that it would require a different .emacs for different screen sizes afaics. But might be the best option.

Comment: It may very well be the same concept that you have cited -- here is the link to the thread I was thinking about:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24957203/2112489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
(setq fringes-outside-margins t)
```